# What is Linux for $DECK and $EOD?

Tags: shell, scripting

In VMS DCL one may embed data in a command file using $DECK and $EOD. What is Linux for this?

Comment: It may be worth explaining in a little more detail how $DECK/$EOL work

Comment: Would someone who has a VMS system add to the question an example that matches the "cat sample.txt << EOF" answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can embed data within shell scripts. How this works is shell dependent. However bash/perl etc. do this in similar ways, using a *heredoc*. e.g. in bash (and similar):

```
$ cat > sample.txt << EOF
a
b
c
EOF
```

will write as input a,b,c up to the EOF, and then `cat` will write that out to sample.txt. Note that EOF is a convention and you can use any label. Try the above on the command line to see more clearly what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Loki also made a tool called [makeself](http://megastep.org/makeself/). This tool can embed compressed data in a shell file and is useful for self-extracting installation scripts.